# Freemarker "Expected a number or boolean, but this has evaluated to a method+sequence"

Tags: freemarker

I have a Boolean in my FreeMarker template "isApprove" and trying to assign a value to a variable juste like that

```
    <#list data.myList as unitObj>
      {
         ... ,
         "isApprove" : ${unitObj.isApprove?c}
      }
      <#if unitObj_has_next>,</#if>
    </#list>
```

but I get an exception from FreeMarker like below

```
freemarker.core.UnexpectedTypeException: For "?c" left-hand operand: Expected a number or boolean, but this has evaluated to a method+sequence
```

I checked the official documentation of FreeMarker they mentioned for the boolean you have to add "?c" but it doesn't work for me, is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but note that the `<#if ...>...</#if>` can be replaced with `<#sep>,</#sep>`. (Also it's better to write `unitObj?has_next` instead of `unitObj_has_next`, but with `#sep` you need neither.)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how does the Java API of `unitObj` look like. Also, your problem is not related to `?c`, it's simply that you don't get a boolean value before it.

If you have `boolean isApprove()` there, then you should write `unitObj.approvate`, to get the boolean value (and after that you can put `?c` of course).

If you have `Boolean isApprove()`, then that's not a valid Java Bean property getter, and it should be renamed to `Boolean getApprove()` in Java. If that can't be fixed, then you can refer to the `isApprove` method itself, but then it also has to be called to get the boolean value: `unitObj.isApprove()`.